# multiline command chunks in bash history into multiple lines

Tags: bash, history, bash-history

In Bash (as well as Bash in WSL), multiline written commands can call-back with up/down arrows correctly also built-in `history` command report them correctly (until I'm still logged-in in bash).

But after exiting from `bash` and press up/down arrows, multiline commands appears each as separate entries and that's because `cat ~/.bash_history` has chucked the command on multiple separate entries and **writing problem** here; the `history` command result messed too.

I have set these options in `~/.bashrc`

```
shopt -s cmdhist lithist
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
```

and now **writing problem fixed** but `history` command still report in multiple line and separate entries (**reading problem** now).

Bash version is 4.3, same issue on v4.4

there is [this bug report](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00025.html) since a long years but no solution yet.

**Update:**

it's also to mention that below multiline command as an example is correctly displaying even after exit Bash:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
echo $i
done
```

but this is failing:

```
awk '
{ print $1}' <<<'first last'
```

**Update 2:**

the issue mentioned above is fixed in Bash v5.0.0+ that changed to recognize entries between "timestamp as delimiter" as single entry of command (*HISTTIMEFORMAT*, *cmdhist* and *lithist* must be set).

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on regular Ubuntu, so this isn't WSL-specific.

Comment: It feels like a bug, the time on that last line differs on every new login

Comment: I also wonder if this doesn't warrant a bug report

Comment: I dont think its the line by it self but the parsing of the file, I cleaned .bash_history and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am using **GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release** on **Ubuntu 19.10**. I checked and confirmed the issue described in your question exists.

I then solved it using the following steps. After that I exited bash multiple times and confirmed the problem is solved on my system. Multi-line commands are saved to the `~/.bash_history` file, retrieved and executed correctly.

---

#Solution:

Please edit your `~/.bashrc` file or create it if it does not exist.

Copy and paste the following three lines into it and save it:

```
shopt -s cmdhist
shopt -s lithist
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
```

From bash man-pages:

> **cmdhist**:
>
> If set, bash attempts to save all lines of  a  multiple-line  command
> in  the  same history entry.  This allows easy re-editing of
> multi-line commands.
>
> **lithist**:
>
> If set, and the cmdhist option is enabled, multi-line commands are
> saved to the history with embedded newlines rather than using
> semicolon separators where possible.

However, `cmdhist` and `lithist` are useful while the shell is still open and working from memory. When you exit the shell, the commands are saved into the `~/.bash_history` file as single lines without any indication as to where a multi-line command starts or ends and then the working memory is cleared. When you run the shell again these lines in the bash history file (including the multi-line commands) will be read one line at a time and each line will be treated and loaded to working memory as a single command even though it could be a part of a multi-line command because the `~/.bash_history` file will look like this:

```
nano .bashrc 
exit
history 
for i in {1..10}
do
echo $i
done
cat .bash_history 
exit
history 
awk '
{ print $1}' <<<'first last'
history
exit
```

Hence the need for `HISTTIMEFORMAT` which will act as a delimiter to separate each command from an other based on its timestamp, be it a single line or a multi-line command. So the `~/.bash_history` file will look like this:

```
nano .bashrc 
#1581635697
exit
#1581635709
history 
#1581635729
for i in {1..10}
do
echo $i
done
#1581635743
cat .bash_history 
#1581635757
exit
#1581635773
history 
#1581635794
awk '
{ print $1}' <<<'first last'
#1581635801
history
#1581635808
exit
```

From bash man-pages:

> **HISTTIMEFORMAT**:
>
> If this variable is set and not null, its value is used as a format string for strftime(3) to print the time stamp associated
> with  each  history  entry displayed by the history builtin. If this
> variable is set, time stamps are  written to the  history file so they
> may be preserved across shell sessions.  This uses the history comment
> character to distinguish timestamps from other history lines.

From now on multi-line commands will be retrieved, treated and loaded into working memory as a whole (without breaking them into single lines and treating each line as a separate command) and the `history` command output will look like this (**even after restarting bash**):

```
raffa@Laptop:~$ history
   1  2020-02-14 05:25:19 nano .bashrc 
   2  2020-02-14 05:25:38 exit
   3  2020-02-14 05:25:50 history
   4  2020-02-14 05:27:50 for i in {1..10}
do
echo $i
done
   5  2020-02-14 05:28:05 cat .bash_history
   6  2020-02-14 05:28:14 exit
   7  2020-02-14 05:28:27 history
   8  2020-02-14 05:28:55 awk '
{ print $1}' <<<'first last'
   9  2020-02-14 05:29:06 history
  10  2020-02-14 05:29:16 exit
  11  2020-02-14 05:29:27 history
```

And multi-line commands will be correctly retrieved, displayed and executed after exit.

---

Notice:

- You will need to restart your current session of bash after editing and saving the `~/.bashrc` file to activate the changes.
- If your current `~/.bash_history` file or bash working memory already contain history lines with formatting errors, you might need to delete (**Please back up first**) your current bash history by running `history -w; history -c` in the terminal which will permanently delete all your current bash history.
- If you want to preserve your existing history, albeit with old entries split into single lines and having placeholder timestamps, then **don't** clear it like suggested above. Instead, **after backing up `.bash_history` and editing `.bashrc`**, run this command:

  ```
  sed -ri.bak '/^#[0-9]+$/{n;b};s/^/#42\n/' ~/.bash_history
  ```

  It adds a line `#42` (a placeholder timestamp) before every line that isn't a timestamp and isn't preceded by a timestamp. After restarting bash, it should store and load new multiline history entries correctly. To correctly load older multilines too, you can then open `.bash_history` in a text editor and delete all `#42` lines that are inside multilines.
- If bash keeps refusing to load multilines properly, make sure that the *first* line in `.bash_history` is a timestamp, i.e. is a hash followed by a number (like `#42`, without any spaces).

Comment: OK, I have installed Bash v5.0.0 and seems it's fixed there which I found these changes notes. `If readline reads a history file that begins with '#' (or the value of
    the history comment character) and has enabled history timestamps, the
    history entries are assumed to be delimited by timestamps.  This allows
    multi-line history entries.` && `The bash-1.14 behavior when ^M is typed while doing an incremental
    search was restored.  ^J may now be used to terminate the search without
    accepting the line.`

Comment: @αғsнιη So, problem solved?

Comment: yes, thanks, I never tested in v5. this issue fixed in Bash v5.0.0. I have seen that they also changed the readline function as well for this matter. I'm will do check in v4 too later.

Comment: Nice to know about Bash 5. Ubuntu 20.04 is shaping up to be a good LTS upgrade from 16.04 I'm using now.

Comment: > If bash keeps refusing to load multilines properly, make sure that the first line in .bash_history is a timestamp, i.e. is a hash followed by a number (like #42, without any spaces).



-- That was the important point for me. It seems that my history file somehow got truncated at the start of the file incorrectly, so I could save multi-line history, but the `history` command was still showing each line as a separate command.