# I need a zenity progress bar using the output of shred

Tags: command-line, zenity, shredding

I want to use the output of `shred` to make a progress bar with `zenity`.

My `shred` command looks like this.

```
sudo shred -vfn 1 /dev/sda
```

I am new to Linux. So I probably miss an obvious solution.

Answer (score 7):

A progress bar is easy ... I guess what you are asking about is how to make it update and reflect the output status from `shred` ... Well, you can use something like this:

```bash
shred -vfn 1 file_toshred |& \
while read -r line; do awk '{print $NF+0}' <<<"$line"; done | \
zenity --progress
```

Notice: I changed `sudo shred -vfn 1 /dev/sda` to `shred -vfn 1 file_toshred` for safety reasons of folks testing the code, but that would work as well.

The `|&` will pipe `stderr`(*needed for parsing `shred`'s output*) as well as `stdout` in Bash ... For other shells not supporting it you might use `2>&1` instead and probably change the herestring(*`<<<"$line"`*) syntax to an `echo "$line" | ...` like so:

```sh
shred -vfn 1 file_toshred 2>&1 | \
while read -r line; do echo "$line" | \
awk '{print $NF+0}'; done | \
zenity --progress
```

To print the output text as well, you can add `echo "# $line";` inside the `while ...` loop and you might want to expand the [`zenity`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/zenity.1.html) window to accommodate the output by setting the `--width=` like so:

```sh
shred -vfn 1 file_toshred 2>&1 | \
while read -r line; do echo "$line" | \
awk '{print $NF+0}'; echo "# $line"; done | \
zenity --progress --width="500"
```

Comment: A pipe continues to the next line, you don't need to escape the newline with ``\``.

Comment: @muru True ... The escapes, however, are for compatibility and history ... Not all shells handle multi-line commands equally, I think ... See for example [multiline command chunks in bash history into multiple lines](https://askubuntu.com/q/1133015)

Comment: Thank you. The second one did work I only had to put ( ) around everything before " | zenity --progress". I also deleted $NF+0 because the progress bar took the values to move the bar forward but I only wanted to get the output of shred  in the text section of --progress.

Comment: @BlackRed You can show both ... I updated the answer for that ... And I don't see why you might need to use the sub-shell `( ... )` syntax for that